# Problem with implementing Adwhirl

Tags: android, adwhirl

Okay so I put in the adwhirl jar and permissions and all that and I add the the layout to my main xml and added the java stuff, I have no errors or warnings so I am very confused on what I am doing wrong. Here is my source code, layout, manifest, and log cat

**JAVA SOURCE CODE**

```
public class ListA extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdWhirlInterface {
    //**Sets the EditText view to txtNumber
    EditText txtNumber = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);

        if (layout == null) {
          Log.e("AdWhirl", "Layout is null!");
          return;
        }

        // These are density-independent pixel units, as defined in
        // http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
        int width = 320;
        int height = 52;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float density = displayMetrics.density;

        width = (int) (width * density);
        height = (int) (height * density);

        AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
        AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
        String keywords[] = { "online", "games", "gaming" };
        AdWhirlTargeting
            .setKeywordSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(keywords)));
        AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");
        AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);

        AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseAppName("AdWhirl Test App");
        AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseCompanyName("AdWhirl");

        // Optional, will fetch new config if necessary after five minutes.
        AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);

        // References AdWhirlLayout defined in the layout XML.
        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout) findViewById(R.id.adwhirl_layout);
        adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
        adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth(width);
        adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight(height);

        // Instantiates AdWhirlLayout from code.
        // Note: Showing two ads on the same screen is for illustrative purposes
        // only.
        // You should check with ad networks on their specific policies.
        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout2 = new AdWhirlLayout(this,
            "46a9e26bb1f5499ab7b00c9807ae034b");
        adWhirlLayout2.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
        adWhirlLayout2.setMaxWidth(width);
        adWhirlLayout2.setMaxHeight(height);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adWhirlLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(adWhirlLayout2, adWhirlLayoutParams);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Below AdWhirlLayout from code");
        layout.addView(textView, adWhirlLayoutParams);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.invalidate();
      }

      public void adWhirlGeneric() {
        Log.e(AdWhirlUtil.ADWHIRL, "In adWhirlGeneric()");

        //**This makes it so that the EditText view can be called
        //**into the dialer
        txtNumber =  (EditText)(this.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber));

        //**Handles what the button dialer is going to do
        final Button btndialer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialer);
        btndialer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent dialIntent=
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:*"+(txtNumber.getText()).toString()));
            startActivity(dialIntent);
            finish();

            Toast.makeText(ListA.this, R.string.Dial_notification,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
              });

      //**Handles what the button redialer is going to do
        Button btnredialer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redialer);
        btnredialer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent dialIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:*"));
            startActivity(dialIntent);

            Toast.makeText(ListA.this, R.string.Dial_notification,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
              });
    }

    //**This calls the contacts view using the button.
    //**Make sure to use import android.provider.Contact.contacts;
    //**Do not use import android.provider.contacts; (this is for an older version)
    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;  

    public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {  
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {

}
    //**Grabs the results for the contact picker and calls it back into the activity.
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            switch (requestCode) {  
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:  
                Cursor cursor = null;  
                String Number = "";  
                try {  
                    Uri result = data.getData();  
                    Log.v(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "Got a contact result: "  
                            + result.toString());  

                    // get the contact id from the Uri  
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  

                    // query for everything email  
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,  
                            null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },  
                            null);  

                    int emailIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);  

                    // let's just get the first email  
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
                        Number = cursor.getString(emailIdx);  
                        Log.v(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "Got email: " + Number);  
                    } else {  
                        Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "No results");  
                    }  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    Log.e(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "Failed to get email data", e);  
                } finally {  
                    if (cursor != null) {  
                        cursor.close();  
                    }  
                    EditText emailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);  
                    emailEntry.setText(Number);  
                    if (Number.length() == 0) {  
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No email found for contact.",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    }  

                }  

                break;  
            }  

        } else {  
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, "Warning: activity result not ok");  
        }  


}
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
          return true;              

      }
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              // Handle item selection
              switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.item1:
                  Intent i = new Intent(ListA.this, straightapp.class);
                  startActivity(i); 
                    finish();
                  return true;

              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
              }
          }

}
```

**MAIN.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.adwhirl"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">
<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker" android:text="@string/GetContacts">
</Button>
<EditText 
    android:hint="@string/hint" 
    android:id="@+id/txtNumber" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone">
</EditText>
<Button 
    android:text="@string/dialer" 
    android:id="@+id/dialer" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="OnClick">
</Button>
<Button 
    android:text="@string/redialer" 
    android:id="@+id/redialer" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="OnClick2">
</Button>
 <com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
        android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ListA"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter>   
<meta-data android:value="bef8fbbc34c64ceaa67d1c230e864150"
        android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>   
</activity>
<activity android:name="straightapp"></activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 

</manifest>
```

**LOG CAT**

```
01-09 12:33:29.586: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(663): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

01-09 12:33:29.586: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(663): CheckJNI is ON

01-09 12:33:29.786: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(663): --- registering native functions ---

01-09 12:33:30.546: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(663): Shutting down VM

01-09 12:33:30.556: DEBUG/dalvikvm(663): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

01-09 12:33:30.576: INFO/AndroidRuntime(663): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

01-09 12:33:31.116: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(671): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

01-09 12:33:31.116: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(671): CheckJNI is ON

01-09 12:33:31.316: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(671): --- registering native functions ---

01-09 12:33:32.077: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.adapter/.ListA }

01-09 12:33:32.117: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.adapter for activity com.adapter/.ListA: pid=677 uid=10037 gids={3003, 1015}

01-09 12:33:32.157: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(671): Shutting down VM

01-09 12:33:32.187: DEBUG/dalvikvm(671): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

01-09 12:33:32.207: INFO/AndroidRuntime(671): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

01-09 12:33:32.927: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(677): Shutting down VM

01-09 12:33:32.977: WARN/dalvikvm(677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.adapter/com.adapter.ListA}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adapter.ListA in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.adapter-2.apk]

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adapter.ListA in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.adapter-2.apk]

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-09 12:33:33.017: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(677):     ... 11 more

01-09 12:33:33.037: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.adapter/.ListA

01-09 12:33:33.567: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4403a418 com.adapter/.ListA}

01-09 12:33:35.176: INFO/Process(677): Sending signal. PID: 677 SIG: 9

01-09 12:33:35.196: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Process com.adapter (pid 677) has died.

01-09 12:33:35.216: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43efbb88

01-09 12:33:43.859: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4403a418 com.adapter/.ListA}
```

Comment: Could you re-model your question a bit? It's a bit of a mess. Maybe Filter out the relevant parts, at least from your logcat?

Comment: should I just put in the errors from the log cat?

Comment: I have formatted your question a good as possible. No one really needs your entire project. Only the most important parts of it. In this case it would have been the logcat output first.

Comment: Okay I see what you are meaning here.

Comment: I have integrated adwrill as above i did not get any ads.In the logcat it is saying configured info not present or expire fetch the fresh data as information not warning or error. Could you please help me what should i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It had nothing to do with adwhirl I went through and broutght my application down to basic and it still force closed so it was all in my main project. its figured out now.